Simplicial $\pi_0$ as homotopy classes $\Delta^0 \to X$ using that $\pi_0$ is left-Quillen
In Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra, Cisinksi defines the connected component functor as
$$\pi_0 \colon \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{Set}, \qquad \pi_0(X) = \mathsf{colim}_{n} X_n,$$
the left adjoint to the constant simplicial set functor $\mathsf{const} \colon \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{sSet}$.
Among other properties, he claims in Proposition 3.1.31 that if $X$ is a Kan complex then $\pi_0(X)$ can be identified with $\Delta^1$-homotopy classes of maps $\Delta^0 \to X$ (which, by the theory already developed in the book, agrees with the hom-set $[\Delta^0, X]$ in the homotopy category of $\mathsf{sSet}$).
I have a proof of this 'by hand', but in the proof he claims that the statement above can be immediately deduced from the fact that $\pi_0$ admits a left derived functor, and that adjoint Quillen functors have adjoint derived functors. (To make sense of this, he equips $\mathsf{Set}$ with the model structure in which all maps are cofibrations and weak equivalences are isomorphisms).
I would like to see a proof that deduces this property as 'formally' as posible, using that $\pi_0$ is left Quillen. Any help would be much appreciated.
